# Using Mojo.Environment.DeviceInfo frameWork

Tags: webos, palm

How can i get Device information using **Mojo.Environment.DeviceInfo** , Pleasae help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this.HEIGHT = Mojo.Environment.DeviceInfo.screenHeight;`

Just swap out screenHeight with what ever you're looking to use

http://developer.palm.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=1860#.DeviceInfo